# Can Pokemon eggs pile up while to collect in the Day Care?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Can I get a backlog of eggs in the daycare? Example, if I leave an egg in the daycare (to be obtained), and get the conditions right to obtain another egg, will there be 2 eggs for me to pick up (even if I have to refresh the area)?

Comment: I WISH! Would be insanely helpful for large batches of eggs (breeding for shiny/IVs). Although could be annoying extra clutter if you're just quickly breeding for dex entries or something.

Comment: Control the wild pokemon population. Spay or neuter your pokemon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the daycare couple will only hold one egg for you. No new egg can spawn until you collect it, even if you wander off and walk all over the map.

Answer (score -2):

On my x version, I just got 2 eggs. Put in a talon flame, and the one before, and got 2 eggs. Only had 2 spaces so not sure if more can happen.